# BST error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am creating a binary search tree. I am having issues with the insert function. As stated in the question title my error refers to the **new initializer expression list treated as compound expression.**

More specifically, this line of code from my insert function.

```
v = new treeNode(n , NULL, NULL);
```

My code:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class BST {
private:
        struct treeNode
        {
                treeNode* left;
                treeNode* right;
                T data;
        };
        treeNode* root;
        int count;
        void insert(const T & n, treeNode * & v);

public:
        BST();
        ~BST();
        void push(const T & n);
        void printPreOrder() const;
        void preOrder(treeNode* pre) const;
        bool search(const T & s);
        bool empty() const;
        int size() const;

};

template<class T>
BST<T>::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
    count = 0;
}


template<class T>
void BST<T>::push(const T & n)
{   
    insert(n,root);
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::insert(const T & n, treeNode* & v)
{
    if (v == NULL)
        v = new treeNode(n , NULL, NULL);
    else if ( n < v->data)
        push(n, v->left);   // goes to left node
    else if ( v->data < n)
        push(n, v->right);  // goes to right node
    else 
        ; // duplicate; do nothing.

}
```

I understand what it means by compound expression, but does it want something more like this?

```
    if (v == NULL)
    treeNode* v = new treeNode;
    v->data = n;
    v->left = NULL;
    v->right = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write an appropriate constructor:

```
    struct treeNode
    {
            treeNode* left;
            treeNode* right;
            T data;

            treeNode(T const& data, treeNode* left, treeNode* right) :
                    data(data), left(left), right(right) {}
    };
```

Comment: Well shoot, if I knew it was that easy. I just didn't fully understand the context of the error. Thank you for your answer and your time! I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me!